# How to change theme to dark on click on IconButton?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my application, in the appBar, there is a button that should change the theme to dark. I need to create functionality  Provider. How can this be implemented? I just need to change the Scaffold color to black and the text color to white.
My main.dart:

```js
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        textTheme: const TextTheme(
          headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          headline5: TextStyle(fontSize: 36.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          subtitle2: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.black),
          bodyText1: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      home: const HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
```

My switch button:

```js
appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter theme config'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {

            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.dark_mode),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Theme provider:

```js
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this :

First we provide our **Provider** globally for the whole application, and then in the attribute *theme*: we listen for the change.

** main **

```
void main() async {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider( // create the provider
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => ThemeProvider(),
        )
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Material App',
      initialRoute: HomeScreen.routerName,
      routes: {
      },
      theme: Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context).currentTheme, // listen to the current theme
    );
  }
}
```

In the provider we will only have two functions, one to switch to **LightMode** and the other to **DarkMode**, then we add it to the **currentTheme** variable which is the one that listens in the **main**

** ThemeProvider **

```
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeData? currentTheme;

  setLightMode() {
    currentTheme = ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.light, // LightMode
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.red,
      [...] // more attributes
    );
    notifyListeners();
  }

  setDarkmode() {
    currentTheme = ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.dark, // DarkMode
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.green,
      [...] // more attributes
    );
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Finally we create a **StatefulWidget** to change the *isDarkMode* variable to call the provider

** Button Home **

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<SettingsScreen> {
  bool isDarkmode = false; // new variable

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Settings"),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: IconButton(
             onPressed: () {
               final themeProvider =
                        Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false); // get the provider, listen false is necessary cause is in a function

               setState(() {
                  isDarkmode = !isDarkmode;
               }); // change the variable

               isDarkmode // call the functions
                  ? themeProvider.setDarkmode()
                  : themeProvider.setLightMode();
             },
             icon: const Icon(Icons.dark_mode),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much) Can you please tell me if I can set custom ThemeData for each theme?

Comment: Sure ! I edited it already, take a look in the ThemeProvider ;)

Comment: Sometimes you might just want to set the Theme Mode. So dark mode is ThemeMode.dark, light mode is ThemeMode.light, and system mode is ThemeMode.system.
 Also, I hear in flutter 3 there are new options for theming which might take some of the weight out of it.